# I get an Ansi string instead of Utf-8 from Utf-8 mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

When I moved from php mysql shared hosting to my own VPS I've found that code which outputs user names in UTF8 from mysql database outputs `?�??????�` instead of `鬼神❗`. My page has `utf-8` encoding, and I have `default_charset = "UTF-8"` in php.ini, and `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in my php file, as well as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in html part of it.

My database has collation utf8_bin, and table has the same. On both previos and current hosting in **phpmyadmin** for this database record I see: `й¬јзҐћвќ—`. When I create ANSI text file in Notepad++, paste `й¬јзҐћвќ—` into it and select Encoding->Encode in UTF-8 menu I see `鬼神❗`, so I suppose it is correct encoded UTF-8 string.

Ok, and then I added

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_bin'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_bin
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

to my.cnf and now my page shows `й¬јзҐћвќ—` instead of `?�??????�`. This is the same output I get in **phpmyadmin** on both hostings, so I'm on a right way. And still somehow on my old hosting the same php script returns utf-8 web page with name `鬼神❗` while on new hosting - `й¬јзҐћвќ—`. It looks like the string is twice utf-8 encoded: I get utf-8 string, I give it as ansi string to Notepad++ and it encodes it in correct utf-8 string.

However when I try `utf8_encode()` I get `Ð¹Â¬ÑÐ·ÒÑÐ²Ñâ`, and  `utf8_decode()` returns `?�???????`. The same result return `mb_convert_encoding($name,"UTF-8","ISO-8859-1");` and `iconv( "ISO-8859-1","UTF-8", $name);`.

So how could I reproduce the same conversion Notepad++ does?
See answer below.

Comment: What MySQL calls UTF-8 is not UTF-8, but utf8mb4 is. See for example https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Currently it is not that important, and moreover - it somehow DOES WORK on my old hosting, even though it is not utf-8 I see JApanese symbols.

Comment: Does the PHP code that stablish the database connection set the encoding explicitly, or it just relies on server defaults? What's the charset/collation of the database tables themselves?

Comment: It's possible something became corrupted when you migrated your data. If you do `SELECT column, HEX(column)` on the same rows both the shared and vps databases you'll be able to see whether this happpened.

Comment: See "question mark" and "black diamond" and "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Keep in mind that the `root` user does not execute `init_connect`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple yet not obvious for me, as I never saw my.cnf on that shared hosting: it seems that that server had settings as follows

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = cp1252'
init_connect='SET NAMES cp1252'
character-set-server=cp1252
```

So to make no harm to other code on my new server I have to place `mysql_query("SET NAMES CP1252");` on top of each php script which works with utf8 strings. 
The trick here was script gets a string as is (ansi) and outputs it, and when browser is warned that page is in utf-8 encoding it just renders my strings as utf-8.

Comment: So in other words you are actually storing garbage in your database. You should fix that and migrate to proper UTF-8 all the way through.

Comment: It's legacy db (from 2010), I'd let it be as is